# gcp monitoring “number of time series series violates”

Tags: google-cloud-platform, monitoring, google-cloud-monitoring

What's the difference between the "number of time series series violates" and  the other conditional triggers? I can imagine what would the other conditional trigger would do easily, but I have no idea what would the this one would do.

How I would interpret "number of time series series violates"  two ways .

for example A :  I can have 5 vm instances , the conditional trigger for   "number of time series series violates" at-least 3 times(one instance becomes absent 3 times) , and "is absent" for a 1 day.

or Example B : I can have 5 vm instances , the conditional trigger for   "number of time series series violates" at-least 3  vm instances would have to exceed  the threshold(become absent) , and "is absent" for a 1 day.

Thank you in advance  for clarifying  my misunderstanding .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Example B is correct, let's assume you have a condition for `VM Instances` and `CPU Usage`. You have 5 VM so you have 5 different time series - one for each VM. When you set `Number of time series violates` that means 3 time series has exceed threshold or you can say 3 out of 5 of the time series are in violation. Alternatively you can use the percentage option and set it to 60% which will yield same result.

Setting longer time frame will give you the behaviour you are describing in Example A